# Pivoting an array in Julia

Tags: julia

Suppose I have an array

```
dt = Array([77 1 2 3 4;20210101 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.3;20210102 -0.1 0.05 0.2 0.3; 20210103 0 0.05 0.7 0.3])
```

[image]

The first row are IDs of companies (The 77 in [1,1] can be ignored). So the array means the data for three companies (1,2,3 and 4) in three days (from 01/01/2021 to 03/01/2021).

What I want to do is to pivot this array so it looks like:

[image]

Here the 3 columns are date, company ID and data, respectively.

To do this, my code is like

```
data_names = Vector(dt[1,:])
dt = DataFrame(dt[2:end,:])
rename!(dt,Symbol.(data_names))
dt = stack(dt:size(dt))
dt = Matrix(dt)
```

However, after these steps, seems the type of the second column is CategoricalValue and I do not know how to convert it.
[image]

Is there any method to do this more easily?

Answer (score 1):

Doing exactly what you asked for, you could have something like

```
function process(dt)
    dates = dt[2:end, 1]
    ids   = dt[1, 2:end]

    A = zeros(length(dates) * length(ids), 3)
    A[:, 1] = vcat(fill.(ids, length(dates))...)
    A[:, 2] = repeat(dates, length(ids))
    A[:, 3] = Iterators.flatten(dt[2:end, 2:end]) |> collect

    A
end
```

However, personally I'd want an Int for the ID and a [Date](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/) for the dates. I would recommend using those and keeping the data as a `DataFrame` if you're going to use it in that kind of fashion. That could look something like this (I don't use `DataFrames` that often so there may be a more optimal way, but this is the idea):

```
using Dates
using DataFrames

function split_date(x)
    day = mod(x, 100)
    x = (x - day) / 100
    month = mod(x, 100)
    x = (x - month) / 100
    year = x

    Date(year, month, day)
end

function better_process(dt)
    dates = dt[2:end, 1] .|> split_date
    ids   = dt[1, 2:end] .|> Int

    DataFrame(id = vcat(fill.(ids, length(dates))...),
              date = repeat(dates, length(ids)),
              value = Iterators.flatten(dt[2:end, 2:end]) |> collect)
end
```

which will give you something like this:

```
julia> better_process(dt)
12×3 DataFrame
 Row │ id     date        value   
     │ Int64  Date        Float64 
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │     1  2021-01-01     0.1
   2 │     1  2021-01-02    -0.1
   3 │     1  2021-01-03     0.0
   4 │     2  2021-01-01     0.1
   5 │     2  2021-01-02     0.05
   6 │     2  2021-01-03     0.05
   7 │     3  2021-01-01     0.2
   8 │     3  2021-01-02     0.2
   9 │     3  2021-01-03     0.7
  10 │     4  2021-01-01     0.3
  11 │     4  2021-01-02     0.3
  12 │     4  2021-01-03     0.3
```

That you can then play with

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, re-using @RolfePower's `function split_date(x)`:

```
julia> using DataFrames, Tables, AxisKeys

julia> ka = wrapdims(dt[2:end, 2:end]; day = split_date.(dt[2:end,1]), ID = Int.(dt[1,2:end]))
2-dimensional KeyedArray(NamedDimsArray(...)) with keys:
↓   day ∈ 3-element Vector{Date}
→   ID ∈ 4-element Vector{Int64}
And data, 3×4 Matrix{Float64}:
                        (1)    (2)     (3)    (4)
   Date("2021-01-01")     0.1    0.1     0.2    0.3
   Date("2021-01-02")    -0.1    0.05    0.2    0.3
   Date("2021-01-03")     0.0    0.05    0.7    0.3

julia> df = DataFrame(Tables.columns(ka));

julia> sort(df, :ID)
12×3 DataFrame
 Row │ day         ID     value   
     │ Date        Int64  Float64 
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │ 2021-01-01      1     0.1
   2 │ 2021-01-02      1    -0.1
   3 │ 2021-01-03      1     0.0
   4 │ 2021-01-01      2     0.1
   5 │ 2021-01-02      2     0.05
   6 │ 2021-01-03      2     0.05
   7 │ 2021-01-01      3     0.2
   8 │ 2021-01-02      3     0.2
   9 │ 2021-01-03      3     0.7
  10 │ 2021-01-01      4     0.3
  11 │ 2021-01-02      4     0.3
  12 │ 2021-01-03      4     0.3
```